# How to position correctly appended element with absolute position?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm working on creating a tooltip function. Basically it appends a div with a tooltip text inside - to an element you clicked at. But how can I always position this element above the element I clicked ad?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tooltipTarget').click(function() {
    var title = $(this).data('tooltip');
    if (!$('p.tooltip').hasClass('active')) {
      $('<p class="tooltip active"></p>')
        .text(title)
        .appendTo($(this));

      $('.tooltip').addClass('test');
      $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        if (e.target != $('.tooltipTarget')[0]) {
          $('.tooltipTarget').trigger('click');
        }
      });
    } else {
      $(document).off('click');
      $('p.tooltip.active').fadeOut(250, function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  margin-top: -45px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 1px;
  color: #767676;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 10;
  max-width: 250px;
  &.active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.tooltip::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: -14px;
  right: 50%;
  right: calc(50% - 7px);
  border-left: solid 7px transparent;
  border-right: solid 7px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 7px transparent;
  border-top: solid 7px #f7f7f7;
}
.tooltip::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  bottom: -15px;
  right: 50%;
  right: calc(50% - 7px);
  border-left: solid 7px transparent;
  border-right: solid 7px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 7px transparent;
  border-top: solid 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>CSS3 tooltip</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">



</head>

<body>

  <button style="margin: 200px;" data-tooltip="This is a tooltipThis is a ltipThis is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is a tootooltipThis is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is his is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is his is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is his is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThis is a tooltipThistooltipThis is a tooltip"
  class="tooltipTarget">orempaks[djo[psad</button>

</body>

</html>
```

P.S. I don't want to use basic html title functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you...

```
button.tooltipTarget {
position: relative;
}

p.tooltip.active {
position: absolute; 
bottom: 100%; 
left: 50%; 
width: 400px;
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the exact position of you click event relatively to a container element, if that would help...

You can gt the `offset` of the clicked element, `PageX`, `PageY` of the mouse click event and calculate where should your tooltip start:

```
  $('#container').click(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var top = e.pageY - offset.top;
    var left = e.pageX - offset.left;

    alert('OFFSET: ' + top + ', ' + left);
  });
```

So your tooltip's `top` and `left` could be set by this calculations.

<kbd>[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/xzwzrtkk/1/)</kbd>

Appending something to the container at the click position: <kbd>[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/xzwzrtkk/5/)</kbd> (With most of your css)

Comment: sry, but I'd prefer not to use calculations for this.

Answer (score 0):

please Try This one:

css code:

```
button.tooltipTarget {
position: relative;
}
p.tooltip.active {
position: absolute; 
bottom: 100%; 
left: 50%; 
width: 400px;

transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.tooltip {
  margin-top: -45px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 1px;
  color: #767676;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 10;
  max-width: 250px;
  &.active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.tooltip::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: -14px;
  right: 50%;
  right: calc(50% - 7px);
  border-left: solid 7px transparent;
  border-right: solid 7px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 7px transparent;
  border-top: solid 7px #f7f7f7;
}
.tooltip::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  bottom: -15px;
  right: 50%;
  right: calc(50% - 7px);
  border-left: solid 7px transparent;
  border-right: solid 7px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 7px transparent;
  border-top: solid 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/bzey92tf/2/)

Comment: You've just copied and pasted my code dude??? set width and indentation all the same!

Comment: yes you are absolutely dude...you are a genius ..thanks @Aaron